# Android WebView resource files like js and css files caching

Tags: android, caching, browser, webview

I am using WebView to load ASP.Net MVC website but loading page is **very slow** because of loading many.js files

But when I load page in browser e.g. Google Chrome then page loading almost 8 times **faster** because browser **cache** the resource files,

I think page is loading slower in WebView because it does not load files from cache. If I do not load resource files (js, css) then web view loading is faster.

My question is how we can make WebView to cache resource files (js, css etc) until they are changed on server as web browser do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the WebView cache to enable caching in WebView.

In the properties of the WebView add the following line:

```
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
```